# XSLT translation web config httpHandlers

Tags: xslt, iis, web-config, httphandler

Since the handlers section in IIS 7 were moved to another section, I want to move these section automatically during the TFS build process.
In that situation I can serve both IIS 6.5 and 7.x environments.

I want to do the following by using XSLT:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="*.New" type="MyHandler.New,MyHandler"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.MyNewFileExtension" type="MyHandler.MNFEHandler,MyHandler.dll"/>
     </httpHandlers>
   <system.web>
</configuration>
```

Must be translated to:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="handler 1" verb="*" path="*.New" type="MyHandler.New,MyHandler"/>
            <add name="handler 2" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.MyNewFileExtension" type="MyHandler.MNFEHandler,MyHandler.dll"/>
        </handlers>
   <system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help me out by making an XSLT for this or point me in to the right direction? (ALSO note:extra atrribute [name] in the second xml)

Ik know how to do easy translations, but moving collections of nodes around in de xml is harder.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="system.web">
    <system.web>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="httpHandlers/*" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="system.web/httpHandlers/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('handler ', position())"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input (after the missing slash on the closing `<system.web>` is added), this produces:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="handler 1" verb="*" path="*.New" type="MyHandler.New,MyHandler" />
      <add name="handler 2" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.MyNewFileExtension" type="MyHandler.MNFEHandler,MyHandler.dll" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>` is probably not necessary, but your example had the opening and closing `<system.web>` in the output on separate lines, so I added that to ensure they would not be combined into a single shorttag (`<system.web />`).

Comment: Thanks very much JLRishe, this works like a charm!
The <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> is indeed not needed, but I know now how to do such a thing.